# Парсинг таблицы с разным количеством строк

Tags: php

Подскажите, как на php получить значения таблицы, с разным количеством строк. То есть есть таблица в виде списка:

```
<ul class="list-reset m0">
        <li class="flex border-top border-light-gray py1">
            <span class="col-4 pr2 italic">Availability</span>
            <span class="col-8 green">6 pcs</span>
        </li>
        <li class="flex border-top border-light-gray py1">
            <span class="col-4 pr2 italic">Brand</span>
            <span class="col-8">FAG</span>
        </li>
        <li class="flex border-top border-light-gray py1">
            <span class="col-4 pr2 italic">Item Number</span>
            <span class="col-8">S6208.2RSR.W203B FAG</span>
        </li>
            <li class="flex border-top border-light-gray py1">
                <span class="col-4 pr2 italic">Technical details (2RSR.W203B)</span>
                <span class="col-8">2RSR=Rubber Seals At Each Side Of The Bearing. W203B=Bearings Of Stainless Steel 1.3541M (X65Cr13).</span>
            </li>
                    <li class="flex border-top border-light-gray py1">
            <span class="col-4 pr2 italic">Category</span>
            <span class="col-8">Stainless Steel Ball Bearings</span>
        </li>
                <li class="flex border-top border-light-gray py1">
                    <span class="col-4 pr2 italic">Inner (d) MM</span>
                    <span class="col-8">
                            40
                    </span>
                </li>
                <li class="flex border-top border-light-gray py1">
                    <span class="col-4 pr2 italic">Outer (D) MM</span>
                    <span class="col-8">
                            80
                    </span>
                </li>
                <li class="flex border-top border-light-gray py1">
                    <span class="col-4 pr2 italic">Width (B) MM</span>
                    <span class="col-8">
                            18
                    </span>
                </li>
                <li class="flex border-top border-light-gray py1">
                    <span class="col-4 pr2 italic">Inner (d) Inch</span>
                    <span class="col-8">
                            -
                    </span>
                </li>
                <li class="flex border-top border-light-gray py1">
                    <span class="col-4 pr2 italic">Outer (D) Inch</span>
                    <span class="col-8">
                            -
                    </span>
                </li>
                <li class="flex border-top border-light-gray py1">
                    <span class="col-4 pr2 italic">Width (B) Inch</span>
                    <span class="col-8">
                            -
                    </span>
                </li>
                <li class="flex border-top border-light-gray py1">
                    <span class="col-4 pr2 italic">Weight (kg)</span>
                    <span class="col-8">
                            0.3670
                    </span>
                </li>
                <li class="flex border-top border-light-gray py1">
                    <span class="col-4 pr2 italic">Manufacturer Part Number (MPN)</span>
                    <span class="col-8">
                            S6208.2RSR.W203B
                    </span>
                </li>
                <li class="flex border-top border-light-gray py1">
                    <span class="col-4 pr2 italic">Bore</span>
                    <span class="col-8">
                            C - Cylindrical Bore
                    </span>
                </li>
                <li class="flex border-top border-light-gray py1">
                    <span class="col-4 pr2 italic">Seal</span>
                    <span class="col-8">
                            2RS - Rubber Seal on Two Sides
                    </span>
                </li>
                <li class="flex border-top border-light-gray py1">
                    <span class="col-4 pr2 italic">Cage Type</span>
                    <span class="col-8">
                            S - Steel or Standard Cage
                    </span>
                </li>
                <li class="flex border-top border-light-gray py1">
                    <span class="col-4 pr2 italic">Radial Internal Play</span>
                    <span class="col-8">
                            Cn Normal Internal
                    </span>
                </li>
                <li class="flex border-top border-light-gray py1">
                    <span class="col-4 pr2 italic">Precision</span>
                    <span class="col-8">
                            Standard Precision
                    </span>
                </li>
                <li class="flex border-top border-light-gray py1">
                    <span class="col-4 pr2 italic">Lubrication</span>
                    <span class="col-8">
                            Standard Lubrication
                    </span>
                </li>
                <li class="flex border-top border-light-gray py1">
                    <span class="col-4 pr2 italic">Heat Stabilization</span>
                    <span class="col-8">
                            No Heat Stabilization - Temperatures up to 120°C
                    </span>
                </li>
    </ul>
```

Как получить значение параметра по заранее известному наименованию параметра.
Мысль такая: нахожу например Availability и беру значение 6 pcs, потом нахожу Brand и беру значение FAG.
Сложность в том, что строк в таблице у другого товара может быть меньше и соответственно просто поиск по номеру строки не подходит (:nth-child(2))

Comment: @InDevX ну почему же никак. https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/ и вперёд

Comment: @InDevX, а разве нельзя разобрать каким-нибудь simle XML?

Comment: @ArchDemon более того, можно использовать даже не библиотеку, а  https://www.php.net/manual/ru/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php и методы объекта DOMDocument

Comment: @ArchDemon? опередили) Подскажите, как обычный ul li список им разобрать? Он у меня в переменной допустим $list

Comment: @СергейМишин во-первых, я не правильно понял задачу, признаю. во-вторых, я не отвечал на вопрос а оставил комментарий как-раз по 1 причине и не уверенности

Comment: Ребята, помогите пожалуйста. У меня в переменной есть этот список и наверное удобнее было бы по нему создать массив где было бы нечно подобное array(
 [key] => value,
 [key] => value,
 [key] => value,
) а далее я бы его foreach прогнал и в нужные переменные записал

Comment: @Batyabest если я правильно понимаю, то с помощью того же DOMDocument - в цикле идет перебор, и если встречается ключ, который необходим, то в текущем наборе элементов берем его следующий элемент. Т.е первый цикл по тегу `li` в котором берем первый элемент спан, у него смоотрим текст, и если совпадает с искомым словом - берем текст второго элемента и делаем break цикла. А сами эти циклы внести внутрь функции. Чтоб сделать функцию `findValueByTagName`

Comment: @СергейМишин помогите кодом пожалуйста, пытаюсь что-то разные ошибки выдает

Comment: @Batyabest было бы конечно хорошо, если бы вы привели код того, что не получается. Но да ладно, я решил написать в ответе, в надежде что вы разберетесь в работе DOMDocument и будете это использовать мудро

Comment: @СергейМишин спасибо огромное!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

с помощью [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.domdocument.php) получается так: в цикле идет перебор, и если встречается ключ, который необходим, то в текущем наборе элементов берем его следующий элемент. Т.е первый цикл по тегу `li`, в котором берем первый элемент `span`, у него смотрим текст, и если совпадает с искомым словом - берем текст второго элемента и делаем выход из цикла (http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0a37e04de74ac806b162cd4c5e433cc8000107c0)

```
<?php
$html = <<<HTML
<ul class="list-reset m0">
        <li class="flex border-top border-light-gray py1">
            <span class="col-4 pr2 italic">Availability</span>
            <span class="col-8 green">6 pcs</span>
        </li>
        <li class="flex border-top border-light-gray py1">
            <span class="col-4 pr2 italic">Brand</span>
            <span class="col-8">FAG</span>
        </li>
        <li class="flex border-top border-light-gray py1">
            <span class="col-4 pr2 italic">Item Number</span>
            <span class="col-8">S6208.2RSR.W203B FAG</span>
        </li>
            <li class="flex border-top border-light-gray py1">
                <span class="col-4 pr2 italic">Technical details (2RSR.W203B)</span>
                <span class="col-8">2RSR=Rubber Seals At Each Side Of The Bearing. W203B=Bearings Of Stainless Steel 1.3541M (X65Cr13).</span>
            </li>
                    <li class="flex border-top border-light-gray py1">
            <span class="col-4 pr2 italic">Category</span>
            <span class="col-8">Stainless Steel Ball Bearings</span>
        </li>
                <li class="flex border-top border-light-gray py1">
                    <span class="col-4 pr2 italic">Inner (d) MM</span>
                    <span class="col-8">
                            40
                    </span>
                </li>
                <li class="flex border-top border-light-gray py1">
                    <span class="col-4 pr2 italic">Outer (D) MM</span>
                    <span class="col-8">
                            80
                    </span>
                </li>
                <li class="flex border-top border-light-gray py1">
                    <span class="col-4 pr2 italic">Width (B) MM</span>
                    <span class="col-8">
                            18
                    </span>
                </li>
                <li class="flex border-top border-light-gray py1">
                    <span class="col-4 pr2 italic">Inner (d) Inch</span>
                    <span class="col-8">
                            -
                    </span>
                </li>
                <li class="flex border-top border-light-gray py1">
                    <span class="col-4 pr2 italic">Outer (D) Inch</span>
                    <span class="col-8">
                            -
                    </span>
                </li>
                <li class="flex border-top border-light-gray py1">
                    <span class="col-4 pr2 italic">Width (B) Inch</span>
                    <span class="col-8">
                            -
                    </span>
                </li>
                <li class="flex border-top border-light-gray py1">
                    <span class="col-4 pr2 italic">Weight (kg)</span>
                    <span class="col-8">
                            0.3670
                    </span>
                </li>
                <li class="flex border-top border-light-gray py1">
                    <span class="col-4 pr2 italic">Manufacturer Part Number (MPN)</span>
                    <span class="col-8">
                            S6208.2RSR.W203B
                    </span>
                </li>
                <li class="flex border-top border-light-gray py1">
                    <span class="col-4 pr2 italic">Bore</span>
                    <span class="col-8">
                            C - Cylindrical Bore
                    </span>
                </li>
                <li class="flex border-top border-light-gray py1">
                    <span class="col-4 pr2 italic">Seal</span>
                    <span class="col-8">
                            2RS - Rubber Seal on Two Sides
                    </span>
                </li>
                <li class="flex border-top border-light-gray py1">
                    <span class="col-4 pr2 italic">Cage Type</span>
                    <span class="col-8">
                            S - Steel or Standard Cage
                    </span>
                </li>
                <li class="flex border-top border-light-gray py1">
                    <span class="col-4 pr2 italic">Radial Internal Play</span>
                    <span class="col-8">
                            Cn Normal Internal
                    </span>
                </li>
                <li class="flex border-top border-light-gray py1">
                    <span class="col-4 pr2 italic">Precision</span>
                    <span class="col-8">
                            Standard Precision
                    </span>
                </li>
                <li class="flex border-top border-light-gray py1">
                    <span class="col-4 pr2 italic">Lubrication</span>
                    <span class="col-8">
                            Standard Lubrication
                    </span>
                </li>
                <li class="flex border-top border-light-gray py1">
                    <span class="col-4 pr2 italic">Heat Stabilization</span>
                    <span class="col-8">
                            No Heat Stabilization - Temperatures up to 120°C
                    </span>
                </li>
    </ul>
HTML;




function getPropValueFromHtmlByName($html, $propName) {
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($html);

    $tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('li');

    foreach ($tags as $tag) {
        $childs = $tag->getElementsByTagName('span');
        if (($childs[0])->nodeValue === $propName) 
            return ($childs[1])->nodeValue;
    }  

    return 'Ничего не найдено!';
}

echo getPropValueFromHtmlByName($html, 'Availability');
```

Comment: По сути здесь вместо этого я смогу присваивать значение нужной переменной: echo getPropValueFromHtmlByName($html, 'Availability'); ?

Comment: А если мне нужно получить значение той строки, наименование у которой меняется? Но есть постоянная часть? речь о Technical details (2RSR.W203B) - то что в скобках может меняться. Можно ли найти по куску Technical details ?

Comment: @Batyabest `По сути здесь вместо этого я смогу присваивать значение нужной переменной:` - да. По куску - это тогда не через точное совпадение сравнивать, а например а) через strpos б) через substr в) по регулярке и т.д.

Comment: спасибо за помощь. Подскажите с таким вопросом: функцию я пускаю. в цикле foreach - ей передаются каждый раз свои данные в зависимости от итерации. И конечно же получаю Fatal error: Cannot redeclare getPropValueFromHtmlByName(). Как можно решить данную проблему?

Comment: @Batyabest по всем вопросам, не связанным с текущим - стоит задавать новый. И да, "Cannot redeclare" совсем никак не связан с тем, что функция пускается в цикле. Вот если какой-то файл подключается в цикле, где объявлена эта функция - вот это намного вероятнее